# get selected option before onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select tag like this

```
<select class="selecttag" onchange="onchangeEvent()">
<option value="1">value1</option>
<option value="2">value2</option>
<option value="3">value3</option>
<option value="4">value4</option>
</select>
```

How can I get selected option before onchange event?

Comment: Can you post the code that you're trying use to get the selected option?

Comment: Please post the code you tried which didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the value in the element's data on a `focus` event.

e.g. something like:

```
$('.selecttag').on('focus', function(){
   $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
})
```

then in the change event you get the `data("value")` back.

e.g.

```
$('.selecttag').on('change', function(){
   var orig = $(this).data("value");
   var newVal = $(this).val();
   // Save the newer value 
   $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
   // Do something with both values!
});
```

### Notes:

- I use jQuery event handlers only above and recommend you do not mix `inline` event handlers with jQuery. This avoid separating the event registration from the event handler and enables the extra event features jQuery provide.
- Using jQuery handlers lets you chain them too:

e.g.

```
$('.selecttag').on('focus', function(){
   $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
}).on('change', function(){
   var orig = $(this).data("value");
   var newVal = $(this).val();
   // Save the newer value 
   $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
   // Do something with both values!
});
```

The focus is actually redundant after the first time, so you can just do it once, like this:

```
$('.selecttag').one('focus', function(){
   $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
}).on('change', function(){
   var orig = $(this).data("value");
   var newVal = $(this).val();
   // Save the newer value 
   $(this).data("value", $(this).val());
   // Do something with both values!
});
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty much the same as the answer in the question that I commented that this question is a dupe of. Please vote to close as such.

Comment: @j08691: looking at the dupe question, I dislike the top answer a lot. You should not have to use IIFEs, just to scope a local value, when `data()` is available :(

Comment: thanks a lot.It works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the previous value in a var, and update it on change. Your `onchange` should be managed in JS:

```js
var prev = $("#select").val();
$("#select").on("change", onchangeEvent);

function onchangeEvent() {
  var curr = $("#select").val();
  console.log("Prev: " + prev, "Current: " + curr);
  prev = curr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" class="selecttag">
  <option value="1">value1</option>
  <option value="2">value2</option>
  <option value="3">value3</option>
  <option value="4">value4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would grab the current value of `#selecttag` prior to doing anything like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected = $(".selecttag option:selected");
    // do whatever after this
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery to get the value.

```
$( "#selecttag" ).val();
```